# D - casting char[] to const char[]

Tags: casting, char, constants, d

I have to use tango.

Im reading from file a text which is an instruction into char[] table. Then I need to execute it through the mixin. The mixin as argument need string or const char[]. How can I cast char[] to const char[]?

```
import tango.io.Stdout;
import tango.io.Console;

void main(char[][] args)
{
int x = 3;

char[] tab = "x = 5;"; 
mixin(tab);                 // throw error 

const char[] tab2 = "x = 5;";
mixin(tab2);               // here it's ok
}
```

ERROR :  Error: argument to mixin must be a string, not (tab)

I know it must be string, but sending const char[] it's working, sending standard char[] it's not so how to make it work ? :<

Comment: Jonathan's answer below is correct. You can read more about this here, http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/const_and_immutable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char[]` casts to `const char[]` implicitly. No cast is needed.

```
auto foo(const char[]) {...}

auto foo(const(char)[]) {...}
```

will both accept any variation of mutability of `char[]` - `char[]`, `const(char)[]`, `immutable(char)[]`, `const char[]`, and `immutable char[]`. Both mutable and `immutable` implicitly convert to `const` in general.

**EDIT (addition after code added to question):**

Actually, I'm shocked that your second line compiles. This has nothing to do with `const` vs mutable. This has to do with compile-time vs runtime. The strings that you pass to a `mixin` must be known at compile time. Normally, that means using a function to return the string (in which case, it's called as part of CTFE) or using an enum (which would be known at compile time). Variables aren't known at compile time and therefore can't normally be used. However, you lucked out with your `const` version, because the compiler knew that the value would never change, and the value was directly initialized, so it knew what it was, and it let you get away with it. If you had had

```
const char[] tab2 = foo();
```

and `foo` had returned the string that you wanted to use, that `mixin` would have failed to compile just like the first on.

Strings for mixins should normally either be directly passed to the mixin, returned from a function (which is called as part of CTFE), or be an enum.

If you want to put the contents of a file in a `mixin`, then you need to use a string import. e.g.

```
mixin(import("foo.txt"));
```

And you'll need to tell the compiler what directory to find *foo.txt* in using the `-J` flag.

Comment: @CSharpBeginner Updated with information on reading from a file.

Comment: I doubt you would use C:/dmd/windows/bin folder to store the files with some code you want to mixin... It would probably be somewhere else.

Comment: I have problem with setting this -J flag :/ I got file "test.d" with code where i got     mixin(import("tekst.txt")) and another file "tekst.txt" where i got simple for loop. These 2 files I got in the same Directory "C:\dmd\windows\bin". When i try to compile and use -J like this :  "dmd test.d -Jpath=C:\dmd\windows\bin" I got error called "file tekst.txt cannot be found or not in a path specified with -J" , any suggest why this happens ?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner Use `dmd test.d -JC:\dmd\windows\bin`. `path` isn't part of the flag. It's the path to the directory where the files to import as strings are. And I agree with DejanLekic that putting files that you want to mixin as strings into your dmd directory is a really bad idea. Those are part of your project, not part of dmd.